# Unable to Open large files in Autodesk Forge Viewer- revit file

Tags: autodesk-forge, document, forge, error-code

We are trying to open revit file in forgeviwer but its not opening.

On Document Load getting errorcode 5 in console window. ie.onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:5

Model Deriavtive Api.

Viewer: autodesk viewer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ErrorCode 5 means file not found. Could you share your code demonstrating how you loaded the model?

Comment: We are uploading large file using uploadChunk.

Comment: We are uploading large files using uploadChunk. $apiInstance = new ObjectsApi( $twoLeggedAuth );
  // Here some code snippet to get all the variable value which are using below  
 $result = $apiInstance->uploadChunk($bucket_key, $object_name,$length ,$content_range,$sessionId, stream_get_contents($fileHandle, $length, $start),null,null);

Comment: Getting error - invalid value for "content_range" when calling ObjectsApi.uploadChunk, must conform to the pattern /^bytes [0-9]+\-[0-9]+/[0-9]+$/    In the code we are passing chunk range value like  $content_range ="bytes ".$start."-".$end."/".$file_size;